# Model in Node/Express

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

In a typical MEAN stack application, the server side have Model, View and Controller, where the Model represents the mongoose model. Suppose that, the application does not access to database directly, rather it is accessing the database via RESTful API, is there any model representation in this case? If yes, what is the model representation?

Answer (score 0):

There are various processes which run sequentially when we do some kind of operation using mongoose. Calling statics, methods, data validations, pre-save hooks are some of them. Now, for a REST API accessing DB there are ways to create these processes.

Let's say we are doing operations on users -

1. Create a service which can validate all the data of a particular user (req.body) using a validator such as [validator.js](https://validatejs.org/)
2. Create methods in that service which can serve as statics or methods same as they are created in a mongoose model
3. You can also create pre-save hooks (method which is always called, like hashing password) if necessary  before sending your data through the REST API

It is possible to create multiple services to validate and modify data as and when necessary in a very nice way by calling them in an order at your route middleware.

For example -

```
router.post('/users', [
  RestService.getUserById,
  UserService.checkForDuplicateUser,
  UserService.validateData,
  UserService.preSaveHook,
  RestService.saveUser
]);
```

So in this way a model representation can be created.

Comment: do you mean the whole code `router.post()` as a model representation? It seems more to be a route config to me.